# How to handle the case of $0^0$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to find the maximum of $f(x,y) = x^ay^be^{-a-b}$ constrained to the triangle $x\geq 0$, $y\geq 0$, $x+y\leq 1$ where $a,b\geq 0$. I have split my problem up into several cases:

1. Look for local maxima on the interior of the triangle. I am simply looking for critical points with the derivative and seeing if they satisfy my constraints. Then use quadratic forms to determine if any critical points are maxima.

*EDIT: I realized I don't have to mess about with the quadratic form since the triangle is compact.

1. Look for local maxima on the boundary. This gives me 3 subcases.

   i. On $x+y=1$. I'm using Lagrange multipliers.

   ii. We have $x=0$. This is where I am running into the issue. The hasty would conclude that $f(0,y)=0$. However, if $a=0$ we have $f(0,y) = 0^0y^be^{-b}$. I have been taught that $0^0$ is an indeterminant form, but have seen many things online stating that $0^0=1$. Depending on which is taken, the problem is affected.

   iii. We have $y=0$. Similar issue to ii.

Any insights are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are a,b fixed? Are they integers?

Comment: We are to assume $a,b$ are arbitrary (real) constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$0^0$ is an indeterminate form, and it is $1$. Indeterminate form does not mean undefined, it just means that limits approaching this form are not determined.

That said, it really depends on your core problem. If $a,b$ are fixed, I'd probably choose $0^0=1$, for continuity sake, since it is $1$ everywhere else on the triangle, and maximum strategies are hard enough without discontinuities. But if $a=0$ is only an approximation, and it is just really small, then $0$ might be right. That's the tricky thing. Zero has to really be zero in the exponent.